# SELECT TOP 10 FROM T using CreateQuery/CreateCriteria/QueryOver<T> at Repository Level not at Entity Level

Tags: nhibernate, c#-4.0, hql, nhibernate-criteria, queryover

I have been facing problem fetching the latest 10 posts made by user.
I wrote the following Nhibernate query as follows.

```
    public IList<T> GetLatest10Posts()
    {
        using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
        using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            var queryString = String.Format("SELECT TOP 10 FROM {0} ORDER BY DateUpdated DESC", typeof(T));
            var returnVal = session.CreateQuery(queryString).List<T>();
            transaction.Commit();
            return returnVal;
        }
    }
```

Exception Thrown

> Exception of type 'Antlr.Runtime.NoViableAltException' was thrown. near line 1, column 11

Note: DateUpdated is the column name and is of DateTime type, which is present in all the inheriting entities.

Is there any luck with QueryOver api as I am trying to achieve something like this:

```
session.QueryOver<T>().Take(10).OrderBy().Desc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a [post](http://sessionfactory.blogspot.com/2011/04/support-for-skip-and-take-in-hql.html) about the HQL syntax for this last year.

In a nutshell, `from {0} order by DateUpdated desc take 10`